# How to convert IEnumerable<char> to IEnumerable<string>?

Tags: c#, lambda

Here is the code:

```
List<string> SecurityCodePreSend = new List<string> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
List<string> SecurityCodeSended = new List<string>();
```

I wanna to add top 15 from SecurityCodePreSend to SecurityCodeSended,so I use `Take` of Lambda to do it.

```
SecurityCodeSended.AddRange(SecurityCodePreSend.Select(n => n.Take(15)));
```

However,Visual Studio report an error that can't convert `IEnumerable<char>` to `IEnumerable<string>`.

I googled and found someone said `string.Concat` can solve it.I tried and failed.

How can I convert `IEnumerable<char>` to `IEnumerable<string>`? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IEnumerable<String>.Select( n => n.Take(15) )` does not do what you think it does: the `n` in `.Select( n => )` represents each `String` value in the parent `IEnumerable<String>`, so `Select( n => n.Take(15) )` gets the first 15 characters of each string value and not the first 15 string values.

(This is because the Linq extension methods work on *any* `IEnumerable<T>` and `String` is `IEnumerable<Char>` (to expose each character in the string)).

You want just this instead:

```
SecurityCodeSended.AddRange( SecurityCodePreSend.Take(15) )
```

### And now, for some pedantry:

I note that your code should conform to the C#/.NET naming conventions:

- Method parameters and (in this case) **local variables** should be `camelCase`
- Public and protected instance members should be `PascalCase`
- Static fields should (in my opinion) be prefixed with an underscore `_`
- Instance members should always be prefixed with `this.`

There's also a raging debate if the C# keyword `string` should be used instead of the proper type-name `String`, and finally `Sended` is not valid English (`en-US`) grammar, the correct form would be `Sent`. If we combine these together your code should be:

```
List<String> securityCodesPreSend = new List<String> { "1", "2", "3", "4" };

List<String> securityCodesSent = securityCodesPreSend
    .Take( 15 )
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I can't help say I would prefer securityCodeSent.AddRange( securityCodePreSend.Take(15) )